# Glassfish: Tentando acessar o servidor através de HTTPS

Tags: http, glassfish, localhost

Possuo o Glassfish 4.0 em execução na minha máquina local. Busquei então adicionar um http listener, da seguinte forma:

```
asadmin> create-http-listener --listeneraddress 127.0.0.1 --listenerport 80 --securityenabled=true --default-virtual-server server --listener_id 0
```

`securityenabled=true` deveria me permitir acessar meu locahost através do httpS. Porém, quando tento acessar o endereço `https://localhost:80/`, meu browser diz que a página não está disponível. Como proceder?

Comment: Provavelmente a porta esta errada. Tente acessar no endereço `https://localhost:443` ou simplesmente `https://localhost/`. Verifique também no log do Glassfish se há alguma mensagem de erro.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira Mas se eu defini o listenerport como 80, ele não deveria escutar por essa porta? E não há erros no arquivo de log : /